# Magento 2 Change Reset Password email template

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2.2

In Magento 2, when editing a customer in the backend you have the option to Reset Password for the customer, when click on **Reset Password**, customer will get an email with a link to reset the password.

[image]

However, I can't find out where to edit the **reset password email template**.

I have tried to create a *new email template* in *Marketing -> Email Templates*. I created the new email template from Reset Password (template). And in *Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration*, under the Pasword Options, I set **Reset Password Template** to the one I created in Email Templates.

[image]

But it has no effect. Magento is still using it's default email templates.

I have made sure it's the correct storeview and I also made sure the cache is cleared.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have checked setting at store view level?

Comment: yes,  it is the correct storeview. I have also set it in default config, no effect. It is still using the default template.

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-password-reset-email-magento-2/ Password reset email template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/

Copy the respective template file to your theme like below

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/email/

And change the template accordingly. It should work.

Comment: Do you know which template does Magento use when we click "Reset password" in Admin Panel? I have even tried to edit the template directly in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_reset_confirmation.html. but it has no effect. maybe I'm editing a wrong template?

Comment: I found it out, it's actaully using the template vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_new.html. I'll try your solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Try it should work.

Comment: It's working. And i accepted your answer :). Thanks a lot for the help. But can I not edit the template in admin? like I described in the post?

Comment: Happy to help!. You cannot edit directly on admin. If you want then you can do it by creating a new template under Marketing tab and then assign that template to forgot password template from Store->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Password Options. There you can find the template select option for reset password and all. If still not work then try to clean the cache and use static content deploy etc. and try again.

Comment: OK, I actaully created a new template under Marketing tab. But I assigned it to the Reset password template from Store->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Password Options. Maybe I should assign the new template to Forgot password template. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Right! You need to assign it to forgot password template.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion regarding the "reset" and "forgot" password templates. "Reset" is actually a confirmation of the password being changed. The email sent to get the link to set a new password is the "forgot" email. To me it was poor labeling and structuring of the fields in the customer configuration that made me confused. The "reset" template should be grouped with the other "change" fields under the "Account Information Options" section/tab in the same configuration - and be labeled something like "Confirmation Changed Password".