# Magento 2.2 Override admin forget password email template still load from vendor

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, email-templates

Hi I have been stuck about 1 day, what I want is override this file in my magento 2:

> vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/email/password_reset_confirmation.html

I have many attempt but still no luck, the magento still load the template from the vendor's template, what I was try is this:

1.copy `vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/email/password_reset_confirmation.html`to `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/email/password_reset_confirmation.html`

2. make new module with this structure :

[image]

3. googling and try aplly the solution from google but still no luck, thi is is the link from any link that I have find in google [Magento 2 Change Reset Password email template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230702/magento-2-change-reset-password-email-template)

so, **how to override the forgot password template for admin**? not for customer

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: Magento uses`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_new.html`  when we click "Reset password" in Admin Panel

Comment: front end using Smartwave/porto, but in admin its seems not using any theme, inside app/design/adminhtml/ just has a empty folder named "Magento"

Comment: @magefms what I want is for admin forget password, not for customer, is it same template?

Comment: yeah it's the same , try and check

Comment: @magefms its just for customer not for admin account (backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Instead of

> Magento/Email

replace with this

> Magento/User

so the path should be like below

> app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Backend/Magento_User/email/password_reset_confirmation.html

and make sure your theme is installed properly.

Your registration.php inside the theme should be like this

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'adminhtml/Magento/backend',
__DIR__);
```

For more information about [Creating Admin Theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html)

EDIT :

And you can load vendor template in admin and make a necessary changes there.

> Go to Log-in -> Marketing -> Email Templates -> Add New Template -> Under **Load default template** -> select your module in your case under **Magento_User** -> choose **Forget Admin Password** -> then finally **load template** to see your template loaded in admin and make changes there.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have followed your step, but when I run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** it give me error like this `Autoload error: Theme 'adminhtml/Magento/backend' from '/home/deki/www/seamart/app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Backend' has been already defined in '/home/deki/www/seamart/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend'` so I edit the registration file from at the word `adminhtml/Magento/backend` ,just change case from `adminhtml/Magento/backend` to `adminhtml/Magento/Backend` the error is disappear but the template still load from vendor nothing change anything

Comment: backend is your theme-name

Comment: @DekiAkbar Just follow this guide for more information about admin theme creation
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Comment: wait I'll check it

Comment: updated check you can edit template by loading in admin as well @DekiAkbar